# Streaming live audio over web

Tags: audio-streaming, html5-audio

I am building a system which will stream 'live' audio onto the web. 
The essence of the system is as follows

1./ record audio with microphone

2./ As the audio is been recorded, convert to an MP3 file

3./ Stream the MP3 file onto the web as it is been generated

So this system will allow people to listen to the microphone recording in real time 
(a few 100ms delay is acceptable)
Also, in my real system, I do not have access to the microphone output, just the MP3 file

I have been searching the web for a solution.
The main solutions I see either streams a pre-existing MP3 file (using html5 audio tag), 
or streaming the microphone signal directly (using Ice & Icecast2).

Neither of these solutions appear to work.  If I try and stream the MP3 file with the 
html5 audio tag, I get audio playback, until the browser has 'caught up' with 
the generation of the MP3 file. (i.e. get the first few seconds of audio).

I have not implemented the Ice & Icecast2 solution but from reading the docs it looks
like it will not work sourcing such a file.

It looks to me that the basic problem is trying to deal with an MP3 which is 
been continiously been updated.
Does anyone have any advice on how I solve this problem ?

Regards
Peter

Comment: Have you tried using ffmpeg and ffserver? You could generate your audio file (in FFM2 format) from the microphone in with ffmpeg, stream it to ffserver on localhost, and simultaneously ffserver will stream the file using an HTTP-accessible URL/port on your machine if that's what you want. See https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html and https://www.ffmpeg.org/sample.html

Comment: Did you find a solution?